# Is there a function that returns the ASCII value of a character? (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, ascii, character, hex

I need a function that returns the ASCII value of a character, including spaces, tabs, newlines, etc...

On a similar note, what is the function that converts between hexadecimal, decimal, and binary numbers?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
char c;
int ascii = (int) c;
s2.data[j]=(char)count;
```

A char **is** an integer, no need for conversion functions.

Maybe you are looking for functions that display integers as a string - using hex, binary or decimal representations?

Answer (score 12):

You don't need a function to get the ASCII value -- just convert to an integer by an (implicit) cast:

```
int x = 'A';  // x = 65
int y = '\t'; // x = 9
```

To convert a number to hexadecimal or decimal, you can use any of the members of the `printf` family:

```
char buffer[32];  // make sure this is big enough!
sprintf(buffer, "%d", 12345);  // decimal: buffer is assigned "12345"
sprintf(buffer, "%x", 12345);  // hex: buffer is assigned "3039"
```

There is no built-in function to convert to binary; you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the ASCII value of a character in your code, just put the character in quotes

```
char c = 'a';
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing internal representation with output. To see what value a character has:

```
char c = 'A';
cout << c << " has code " << int(c) << endl;
```

Similarly fo hex valuwes - all numbers are hexadecimal numbers, so it's just a question of output:

```
int n = 42;
cout << n << " in hex is " << hex << n << endl;
```

The "hex" in the output statement is a C++ manipulator. There are manipulators for hex and decimal (dec), but unfortunately not for binary.

Answer (score 0):

As far as hex & binary - those are just representations of integers. What you probably want is something like printf("%d",n), and printf("%x",n) - the first prints the decimal, the second the hex version of the same number. Clarify what you are trying to do -