# is there a function to identify what letter is the char in a string C

Tags: c, string, char

i know there is `isalpha(_)` function for the string.h but i'm just wondering if there is a function for us to know what letter is the specific char in a string. and i want to change it with another specific char such as all A will become "#--" and all K will become "--#" and all other letters has its own differences (also is this possible? to make a substring? inside a string? or am i doing it wrong..)

```
char string[100];

int i;

char A*[]={"#--","--#"};

gets(string);

for(i=0, i<100, i++) {
    if(isalpha(string[i])) {
        string[i]=A[1];
    }
}
```

but i don't know a function that tells me what letter that is.. i know it's a letter.. i know what letter is it.. but the computer/compiler doesn't know what letter is it, it just know if its a letter or not..

Can we also use the `strcmp(_)`? as an alternative? like if we make another `char` that we just put the whole alphabet letters in order?

```
char alpha[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'*you get the point* };

char string[100];

int i;

char A*[]={"#--","--#"};

gets(string);

for(i=0, i<100, i++) {
    if(strcmp(alpha,string[i])==0) {
        string[i]=A[1];
    }
}
```

or should i use the ASCII table? because we tested it out

```
printf("%d , %d \n", 'A', 'a');
printf("%c, %c \n", 65, 97);
```

this out puts:

```
65 , 97
A , a
```

what is the best move to do here?

Comment: aer you looking for the position of a char in the string? If so, use http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strchr.htm

Comment: And if you are looking for the value of a character in the ASCII table (i.e A = 65, a = 97) then use the ord() function

Comment: @Mawg: `ord()` is not a standard library C function. Can you tell where it is from and how to use it? And why it's necessary to have a function at all, given C's native "a string is an array of char" implementation?

Comment: thank you.. for the strchr function.. i did say i want to identify what letter the user input.. oh well

Comment: oops, Ord() is Pascal ;-(   you can actually just cast. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845710/is-there-a-function-that-returns-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-c

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, make yourself an array which contains the replacement characters. Then, access this array by the character you want to encode. Access is done by assuming that the char is an ASCII char, simply subtract the offset from the ASCII table (e.g. 65 if for letting it begin at A) and access your array. E.g.

```
char *code = [ '1', '2' ];

char input = 'B'; // 66 in ASCII
char output = code[input - 65];
```

**Edit**: of course you can do the same with e.g. `char` coding to `char*` (e.g. strings). Just use an array of strings instead of an array of characters.

Comment: Note that the last line needs more work than OP's naieve `string[i]=A[1];` (but I can see proper justification for a "left as exercise to the reader" there).

Answer (score 2):

`char c = 'A'` and `char c = 65` is **exactly** the same thing.

If you want to compare 2 chars, just use the `==` operator:

```
char c = 'A';
char c2 = 65;

if (c == c2)
  puts("It is equal!");
```

From this you can then create some functions/macro if you want to "abstract" the condition:

```
#define IS_LETTER(X, L)   (X == L)
#define IS_LETTER_A(X)    (IS_LETTER(X, 'A'))

char c = 'A';
if (IS_LETTER_A(c)) // or IS_LETTER(c, 'A')
   puts("It's an A");
```