# Alphabetical comparison of two strings in C

Tags: c, string

My programming experience is extremely scattered and I can't seem to find the answer to what I hope is a simple question. I had an assignment last week that I didn't properly finish and it's bugging me to death.

I was supposed to compare two strings alphabetically without using strcmp and find out which string is alphabetically first via a function using pointers.

```
int strcmp373(char *str1, char *str2) {
  while(*str1 != '\0')
  {
    str1++;
  }
  while(*str2 != '\0')
  {
    str2++;
  }
if(*str1 == *str2)

}
```

This is my horrible attempt, my thought process being to use the null terminated value. I was hoping I could get some insight and explain how it works?

Here's a copy of the assignment specifications for reference.

Write a function called strcmp373, which compares two strings in precisely the same way that strcmp does in the C library . This time, please use "pointer syntax" in writing this function. That is, the [ ] operator should not be used at all when referring to particular characters in string1 and string2; instead, all parameters and local variables should be declared as pointers (using the * symbol). Please be sure that you emulate the strcmp C function. Note that strcmp returns 0 if the two strings are equal, even though 0 normally means false in C. The sign of other return values matters is used to indicate in what way the strings are not the same, but the precise return value is not important. 
You may not use any of the built-in C string library functions to complete this code.

Here is the prototype of this function:

```
int strcmp373(char *, char *);
```

And here is a main function which you can use to test strcmp373.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hw3.h" // to be discussed

int main() {
char str1[81], str2[81];
char again = 'y', newline;
while (again == 'y') {
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Enter another string\n");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    int comp = strcmp373(str1, str2);
    if (comp < 0)
        printf("%s is alphabetically before %s\n", str1, str2);
    else if (comp > 0)
        printf("%s is alphabetically after %s\n", str1, str2);
    else printf("%s and %s are the same\n", str1, str2);
    printf("Again? (y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c%c", &newline, &again);
}
}
```

Comment: This will always compare just the final zeroes ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of string alphabetically (case sensitive, nonstandard collation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646734/how-to-sort-an-array-of-string-alphabetically-case-sensitive-nonstandard-colla)

Comment: @Lashane: that proposed duplicate is specifically asking for a *nonstandard* collation - this here is 'the usual' comparison.

Comment: @Jongware
Thanks for the reply. Could I get a push in the right direction? Some of these basics seem to elude me, lol

Comment: The trick is to start comparing at the *first* character of each word, then (if equal of course) continue with the next. Try it on paper, with `LOGIC` and `LOOP` written out and compare them one letter a time.

Comment: @Jongware
Ok so, the loop will continue if the strings are equal and continue through the two until it reaches G, at which point the loop breaks. At that point how would I figure which is alphabetically first?

Comment: @Jongware question to it contains c version of string sorting with _standard_ collation too

Answer (score 8):

Let's say `str1` points to something that holds "abcd" and `str2` points to something that holds "abc".

```
str1
|
v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

str2
|
v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

When you execute

```
while(*str1 != '\0')
{
  str1++;
}
```

You move `str1` until it points to the null character.

```
str1
|
v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

    str1
    |
    v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

        str1
        |
        v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

            str1
            |
            v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

                str1
                |
                v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Similarly, when you execute

```
while(*str2 != '\0')
{
  str2++;
}
```

You move `str2` until it points to the null character.

```
str2
|
v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+

    str2
    |
    v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+

        str2
        |
        v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+

            str2
            |
            v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

When the `while` loops are done, both `str1` and `str2` point to a null character. Hence, `*str1 == *str2` always evaluates to `true`.

What you need is to compare `*str1` and `*str2` and then increment them together if they are equal until they are not equal or you reach the end of the strings.

```
str1
|
v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

str2
|
v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+

    str1
    |
    v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

    str2
    |
    v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+

        str1
        |
        v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

        str2
        |
        v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+

            str1
            |
            v
+---+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+----+

            str2
            |
            v
+---+---+---+----+
| a | b | c | \0 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

Now that you know they are not equal and `'d'` is greater tha `'\0'` return a positive value indicating the LHS is alphabetically greater than the RHS.

That logic can be implemented using:

```
while ( *str1 != '\0' && *str1 == *str2 )
{
   ++str1;
   ++str2;
}

return (*str1 - *str2);
```

Comment: @R Sahu

Wow, thank you! I don't know why I took so long to post myself on stack, lol. I tried it and it worked but I'm missing something. By the way I'm reading it wouldn't the longer word always be greater alphabetically?

Comment: @Ben, No. The loop will break if `*str1` is not equal to `*str2`. If `str1` points to "xyz" and `str2` points to "abcdef", the function will return with a positive value.

Comment: @R Sahu
So in that case it would break on the first character, correct? That being the case by subtracting str2 from str1 the result would be positive because a > x... right?

Comment: @R Sahu
Awesome, thank you for all the help! The visuals clicked with me, haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(*str1 == *str2)
```

You have an if statement with no body in your code excerpt.

Apart from that your program is counting the amount of characters in the character array passed to that function. This won't really achieve your goal.

Lets call each char array a word. What you want to do is find which 'word' comes first in the alphabet. I suggest looking at an ASCII table.

Each letter in either word has a corresponding ASCII number value. If you can figure out how to access the number value of each of these letters, you can compare the strings and the lower value will be higher up in the alphabet.

Unless they are capitalized. That will require a little more work. Here is an ASCII table where you can see the difference.[image]

[This will get you started with figuring out how to get the ASCII value of these letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845710/is-there-a-function-that-returns-the-ascii-value-of-a-character-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. I know my code was completely broken I just got frustrated that point and figured it was time to create an account here to figure out what I'm doing, so I just posted what I had.

So the real issue is figuring out how to convert the string to ASCII and at that point I could return that value back to the main function and compare it that way, correct?

Comment: The ASCII table is not needed. The elements of the string are the character codes that you need to compare.